# How to convert a type of "any" in kind "UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>" in a swift 3

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I updated my xcode for the latest beta and there was such a problem.
Before my code worked well in objective-c:

```
short * pointers = (short *)[[params valueForKey:@"Pointers"] pointerValue];
```

Then I translated part of the code on the swift language:

```
let pointers = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>(((params["Pointers"] as AnyObject).pointerValue)!)
```

Here, too, everything is good. [But this code is not working on the Swift 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiBmc.png). Tell how you can implement on a swift 3. Thank You!

Comment: Try casting to NSValue, `(params["Pointers"] as NSValue).pointerValue`

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the answer. Error: "Can not invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer <Int16>' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer)'

Comment: @LeoDabus             let dataA = unsafeBitCast((params["Pointers"] as! NSValue).pointerValue, to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>.self). Working! :) .Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of converting a pointer to `UInt16` which is wrapped in an `NSValue`
to `UnsafeMutablePointer<Int16>` in Swift 3 is

```
if let ptr = value.pointerValue {
    let u16ptr = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self)
    // ...
} else {
    // pointer is nil
}
```

In your case it should be

```
if let ptr = (params["Pointers"] as? NSValue)?.pointerValue {
    let u16ptr = ptr.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt16.self)
    // ...
} else {
    // value does not exist, is not an `NSValue`, or pointer is nil
}
```